# Will CPU in 64-bit mode executing a call or ret instruction check the segment limit of the stack segment?

Tags: assembly, x86-64

When I read the Intel manual about the execution process of the ret instruction, I saw that even when the CPU is running in 64-bit mode, it still checks whether the pop operation violates the limit of the stack segment and generates a #SS(0), but the section about limit checking clearly indicates that limit checking for a segment is disabled in 64-bit mode.

Comment: I vaguely recall that the limit check might still apply to cases where you wrap around the address space (`ret` when `rsp = 0xfffffffffffffffc` or something like that), but I'm not sure.

Comment: I read that segment checking in 64-bit mode is mostly disabled but not completely disabled. Some segment checks are still performed. The Intel manual refers to this several times. Use a search in the Intel pdf manual to find all references.